# overwrite daily cpanel backup

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I want to make cpanel backups daily which overwrite the old backups after 7 days AND i only want to back up certain folders and databases. The idea is to save space on the backup server.

For example make a backup of each day of the week starting on eg monday.zip, tuesday.zip and then replace these each week. The backups should contain public_html/folder1 and user_databasename1.sql only.

Can this be done? I found this handy script and tutorial but it only partly solves it.

http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/12/27/automatic-cpanel-backup-domain-mysql-with-cron-php/

I don't have WHM access.

Answer (score 0):

cPanel only have FullBackup support, so you can't backup certain folders and databases, if you really want do it you would have to program a complete Script to do that without cPanles API Help (like your sample script from justin-cook.com use).

I did [cPanel-automated-system-backup](https://github.com/eduestrella/cPanel-automated-system-backup) code to make a Full Backup using cPanel API and upload via FTP to a server and store 5 daily old backup by default (you can configure it to 7) and for new month and new years it will backup in monthly and yearly differents folders. I hope that can help you.